# GraphQL how to make relational queries?

Tags: graphql

I am using GraphQL Express:

[image]

I am trying to run this query on relational data by property of related node:

```
{
  Employee {
    name
    Item(name: "Laptop") {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

But it is giving an error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Unknown argument \"name\" on field \"Item\" of type \"Employee\".",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 4,
          "column": 10
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

*[Check Generated Schema Here](http://148.251.5.132:5000/schema)*

*[You can try it out here](http://148.251.5.132:5000/graphiql?query=%7B%0A%20%20Employee%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20Item(name%3A%20%22Laptop%22)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20name%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)*

What am I missing? Are they not supporting this kind of functionality yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as the error indicates there is no argument called `name` on the field `Item`.

Looks like they've got some invalid characters in their schema at the moment, which is causing issues with the GraphiQL interface loading correctly, but normally you could click on any field on the left hand side to open up the Docs panel and get additional details, including what arguments, if any, are available for it. Alternatively, you can press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> to activate the auto-complete (or just start typing).

Answer (score 0):

The bigger problem is that you are using the name casing for queries as you are typesj.

You think you are trying to query all Employee types, but in fact it's hitting the `Employee` query which only has a `name` field, so Item (which should be `item: Item`) does not exist.

TL;DR, use capitalized strings for types, like `Employee` and non-capitalized names like `employees` to indicate a query that returns a number of Employee type instances.